# Can't get 200 status code from post request to Rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, httparty

I have this in my Pizzas controller:

```
def post
  render :nothing => true, status: 200 
end

def get
  render :nothing => true, status: 200 
end
```

My routes:

```
 get '/' => 'pizzas#get'
 post '/' => 'pizzas#post'
```

And this is how I post to that route:

```
require 'httparty'
response = HTTParty.post('https://example.com', {})
p response.code #returns 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
```

What is the reason for this? With **GET** request to that route I reliably get `200`. How to get code `200`?

Comment: You're posting to where your app is rooted to, not the post action in your controller.

What is in your routes?

Comment: @japed, I did, thanks for the reminder, I'll add my routes to the question now.

Comment: where are you posting? does it require you send JSON?

Comment: @neo, no, it doesn't require me to send JSON. By the way, if it could be helpful - there is a `before_filter` in pizzas controller, which invokes a method that talks to websockets and creates a record in database.

Comment: can you show the function you call on the before_filter?

Comment: @Alfonso, thank you for trying to help! figures the problem was in authenticity tokens.

Answer (score 0):

It figures I had to get rid of `protect_from_forgery` line in my *application_controller.rb*. 
The **GET** request was passing through because it doesn't require authenticity token (the one that you see in form created by rails helpers).